# ELIFECYCLE npm error

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

This is the error in my console

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! sedona@0.1.0 start: `npm run build && gulp serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sedona@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-21T19_40_30_516Z
-debug.log
```

This is the "debug.log" file from AppData/Roaming etc. path

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.2.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~prestart: sedona@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: sedona@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: PATH: D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\User\Desktop\user.github.io\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\bin;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\cmd;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\share\vim\vim74;C:\Users\User\Desktop\cmder\
9 verbose lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\User\Desktop\user.github.io
10 silly lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build && gulp serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle sedona@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: sedona@0.1.0 start: `npm run build && gulp serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid sedona@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\user.github.io
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.2.1
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error sedona@0.1.0 start: `npm run build && gulp serve`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the sedona@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

I have already downloaded another gulp-sass projects from other peolpe github's and replace it contains with my own html-sass-js-img files. Error still here btw.

I have already reinstall cmder and node.js. Twice. Error still here.

I have already delete "node-modules" folder from my project and made "npm i" command - nothing changed.

And one fun thing - files in folder "build" updated like always (if you manual lauch them in browser like in old times). But in root folder seems like gulp-sass just don't see that anything happen and zero changes displayed in localhost 3000.

My previous build from yesterday work fine (seemingly) and builds from another people from github work fine too, but why my new build with some changes make that crash??? Only cause sass files changed?

Comment: Seems like it fixed for me....for now.

What I have did:

1. Turn off my antivirus and firewall

2. Run "npm cache clean" command in console

3. Deleted folder "node_modules" in my project

4. Run "npm install --save" (this step passed fine and without errors only when I turned off antivirus and firewall)

For now is working well....

Comment: I had the same problem but simply running `npm cache clean --force` solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

So, there's an interesting cause of this in Jest in VSCode while debugging with Node 12.4.0. When running jest and babel, and placing breakpoints in static classes, the second you place them in the static class, in a static method, node throws this error. To fix, dont write weird static classes.