# Looking for possible reasons why Next.js Node Server crashes: "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE errno 3221225477"

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

This happened on node version 14.16.0. I encountered the error twice now.
The first time i created a react component with the @mui/lab/DateTimePicker. 
I didn't have to install it since @mui/lab was already existing in the project. (tried to reproduce this on another branch(very few changes apart). Didn't work so probably has nothing to do with mui itself) 
The second time was also the second approach to the time input component. Using another simpler node module which i had to install this time. (also couldn't reproduce this case) (worked like a charm the second time)

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\develop\strapi-nextjs-poc\nextjs\.env
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
event - compiled successfully in 5.7s (2008 modules)
wait  - compiling /...
info  - Using external babel configuration from C:\develop\strapi-nextjs-poc\nextjs\.babelrc
[styled-jsx] Loading plugin from path: C:\develop\strapi-nextjs-poc\nextjs\node_modules\@styled-jsx\plugin-sass\index.js
event - compiled successfully in 6.9s (2236 modules)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! nextjs@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nextjs@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-17T12_52_28_233Z-debug.log
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 37:  3732 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

Reverting the current changes sadly doesn't do anything. Even after removing all changes since the last working commit, the branch is still broken. 
What i tried so far (in this order):

- remove dependencies from sourcecode und package json (just removed everything since last working commit)
- deleted .nextjs folder (for caching)
- deleted node_modules folder
- using nvm to remove the current node version and re-installing it
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install`

After encoutering the error once, it seems to be a permanent issue on the branch (even for other people pulling). So the branch is basicly not useable anymore.

The only way i found to fix the recurrence of the error was upgrading node. Tried with v14.19.0 
This just brings the problem of other possible problems with the node version in the project.

Any ideas why this is happening, what causes it or what might fix it?

full log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~predev: nextjs@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: nextjs@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: PATH: C:\Users\sk\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\develop\strapi-nextjs-poc\nextjs\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\sk\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\sk\bin;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python39;C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu11.35.13-ca-jdk11.0.5-win_x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python38\Scripts;C:\Python38;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\adminal\.jpm\windows\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Users\sk\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: CWD: C:\develop\strapi-nextjs-poc\nextjs
10 silly lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle nextjs@0.1.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: nextjs@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sk\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sk\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid nextjs@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\develop\strapi-nextjs-poc\nextjs
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error nextjs@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the nextjs@0.1.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on error code - it looks like a win32 access violation error as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756101/npm-err-errno-3221225477-error-in-node-when-making-a-query-using-oracledb/58959576#58959576)

NodejS 14.6 is on maintenance mode - consider upgrading to 16 or 17

https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

[image]